# How to set correct cookies Value against AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey while initialising AVURLAsset

Tags: ios, avplayer, avurlasset

I have to play HLS stream and it is secured/protected. In order to download manifest file and further ts file it is expected that request have valid Cookies information sent. I do receive Cookies information from server but it is not part of response header whereas it comes as part response String. It means Cookies automatically does not become part of NSHTTPStorage and application have to consume response string and fetch Cookies information from there; further need to be set while initialising AVURLAsset. As per AVURLAsst documentation in order to send Cookie information we should use options "AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey". I have mentioned in below code how to initialise AVURLAsset using this key

```
    let cookieOptions = [AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey: Any]
    let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
```

My main problem how to set value against AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey. It take value of 'Any' type.Since Apple just mention it expect Any value and does not tell how internally it interpret and convert that value in correct format.

I tried two approach to set value: Say I have to set two Cookies key viz MyCookies1, MyCookies2

### Approach 1 using NSHTTPStorage

```
let propertiesKey1 = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain : "Domain=abc.com",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path:"/",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure:true,HTTPCookiePropertyKey.init("HttpOnly"):true,HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value:"abc1",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name:"MyCookies1"] as [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]
let propertiesKey2 = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain : "Domain=abc.com",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path:"/",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure:true,HTTPCookiePropertyKey.init("HttpOnly"):true,HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value:"abc2",HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name:"MyCookies2"] as [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]
let cookieKey1 =   HTTPCookie(properties: propertiesKey1)
let cookieKey2 =   HTTPCookie(properties: propertiesKey2)
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookieKey1!)
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookieKey2!)
let cookiesArray = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!
let cookieArrayOptions = [AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey: cookiesArray]
guard let url = URL(string:"abc.com") else { return }
let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
```

But this is not working and AVPlayer just initializing and stopped working

### Approach 2

```
 let values = ["Cookie": "MyCookies1=abc1; MyCookies2=abc2"]
 let cookieArrayOptions = [AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey: values]
 guard let url = URL(string:"abc.com") else { return }
 let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
```

But this options always crashes.May be I am not setting values in correct format.

I have tried to provide as much information as possible but let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2):

After couple of tries I am able to make it working with Approach 1 usign NSHTTPStorage.  I made a mistake of not using HTTPS streaming URL. I had already allowed to play non-HTTP url by passsing ATS and allow arbitrary loads. But AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey expect to provide only HTTPS url to be set for cookies. I used HTTPS streams and ultimately Cookies started to be sent internally in request header while downloading manifest/segment file in playing HLS stream